# Spirals are not exported with modifier properties (glTF file format) in animations

Tags: animation, materials

In my project the exported glTF file does not preserve the modifier properties set to spirals when the animation runs, causing these spirals to float independently without any attachment to the armature rig. These spirals are however working correctly when the rig is played around with in Pose Mode. I'm a novice when it comes to Blender but I figured it has to do with the animation settings.

(I tried baking the animation, but that removed the springs altogether)

[video displaying the issue](https://vimeo.com/826635472?share=copy)

[image]

Comment: here is a link to the zipped project

https://www.mediafire.com/file/g10jbddepjb64nr/mashalla.blend.zip/file

Comment: Only some animation features are supported by the glTF exporter. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.3/addons/import_export/scene_gltf2.html?highlight=gltf#animation

Comment: Maybe this answers of how to animate a spring will be helpful. This is also glTF compatible: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/275603/animating-a-spring-in-a-unity-compatible-way/275840#275840